# URL Case Sensitivity (Unbounce Landing Pages)

Tags: plugins, urls

I'm using the Unbounce landing page plugin to create landing pages on my Wordpress website. Currently, the website treats page ULRs the same if they do or don't contain capitalization. The Unbounce landing page URLs can't contain any capitalization and the website returns 404 errors if they do.

Does anyone know how to configure the Wordpress website to properly handle the different types of Unbounce URLs?

I wonder if something like this would help: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/uppercase-to-convert-lowercase-in-url/

Thanks!

Comment: I would contact Unbounce customer support. I have it installed and in their interface it won't let me set a URL that contains any capitalization. I keep my Unbounce vs. non-Unbounce URLs separate by adding an underscore to all of my Unbounce pages, i.e. example.com/_landing/ .

Comment: Thanks for the reply @WebElaine. I did speak with the Unbounce customer support and they suggested the plugin I mentioned above but I am skeptical that it will work. (Especially since all of my website URLs already handle capitalization just fine.)

Comment: I'd fall back to classic WP troubleshooting then - deactivate all the other plugins and revert to a default theme, check the URLs in an Incognito window to make sure your browser cache doesn't redirect anything, then swap themes and test, then activate plugins one by one and test. I don't think this is normal WP behavior, unless maybe you're running WP on Windows.

Comment: I'm now wondering if I could resolve this by editing my httpd.conf file... Does anyone know if I can edit this file via Cpanel?

Comment: It depends on the host.